# Check if a website's form is submitting to a database

Tags: database, forms

General question: Assuming someone has normal viewing access to a form/survey (say a google form as an example), what would be the ways to tell if the form is actually using the data you imputed and doing something with it rather than just pretending it was submitted?

I have a specific case like this where I think that I'm looking at a fake form that doesn't submit to any database, etc. but I'm not entirely sure what I would be looking for to confirm that.

I initially looked to see what the form submitted to and it goes to another html page, and I viewed the code on that page too, and it has only html and no PHP or JS. Is it still possible that it submits to a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot know what, if anything the server will do with the submitted values unless you have access to the code running on that server.

Comment: So if a html form redirects to another html page and not a php page it can still send info to a database, correct?

Comment: A redirect is different than a POST. If the form **literally** says `<form action="index.html">`, then you can be assured that there is no PHP running, however, it could still be sending data elsewhere with AJAX. Ultimately, you cannot know what a site is doing with a form submission.

Comment: Index.html could even be a script, although it would be rather uncommon.

Comment: Here's an example of a page that seems like it would just be static HTML, but actually it is running a script (and could intercept POST args) on server-side: http://www.bemmu.com/totally_not_a_script.html